# Repairing al wire run to my barn

Tags: electrical

I have three phase aluminum wire from my house (all copper) to my barn (all copper). Damaged by water erosion at an al/al splice. Should I replace with all cu or repair the al?
The al lines run from main breaker box in the house approx 150 ft. (Barried)To the barn breaker box.

Comment: Aluminum is a natural for heavy feeders between panels. Novices tend to be afraid of aluminum because of stuff they heard, relating to an incident in the 70s that applied to small branch circuits, where UL failed to properly certify wire terminals for Al wire due to time pressure from the government. While the problem was fixed with vast overkill, it is not worth using aluminum small wires because home buyers are prejudiced about it.  But for heavy feeder, aluminum has always been reliable. If safety is your goal, there are 99 other better choices for your $.

Comment: "(Barried)" is this supposed to be "buried"? If not what's that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 4):

**Repair the aluminum.**

There is nothing inherently wrong with aluminum between panels. However, you should address the root cause, particularly because anything involving water + electricity is not a good thing.

Comment: Especially with the cost of aluminum wire significantly less than copper for similar power capacity, for such a long run, it only makes sense to use AL.  Just make sure to use proper joining methods to non-aluminum connections as required by local regulations.

Comment: Make sure the repair splice is inside an appropriate and approved junction box and that it remains accessible for possible future repairs.

Comment: @FreeMan True. But OP already stated "Damaged by water erosion at an al/al splice", so this is replacing an existing, presumable accessible, splice, not adding a new splice (e.g., for animal chewed through wires).

Comment: Always good to check...